# Unable to toggle bluetooth on Kubuntu 21.10 Controller not found

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth

I have 3 other PCs which run bluetooth without issue, all Kubuntu 21.10. On the troublesome PC there is an issue with switching bluetooth on. Going to System Settings> Bluetooth I have this screen:

[image]

If I click on Enable nothing happens.

There is also a bluetooth icon in the task bar:
[image]

Likewise, if I click the bluetooth icon>turn on, nothing happens. Once clicked, the icon disappears.

The bluetooth dongle seems to register:

```
ethan1@ethanubuntu:~$ rfkill list
enter code here
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Bluetooth service appears to be running:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-12-31 06:57:52 AWST; 4min 13s ago
   Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 1752 (bluetoothd)
 Status: "Running"
  Tasks: 1 (limit: 9317)
 Memory: 1.6M
    CPU: 17ms
 CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
         └─1752 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
```

Yet running:

```
ethan@ethanubuntu:~$ sudo hcitool dev
Devices:
```

Says the dongle is not found as no devices are found.

Same with bluetoothctl:

```
ethan@ethanubuntu:~$ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# show
No default controller available
```

Anyone have any ideas/suggestions, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command line to enable bluetooth:

```
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

Comment: Thank you for your responses but further investigation seems to point to a kernel issue: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=60824

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me after a system package upgrade, I have to shut down the system and boot it again to fix the problem.
Only power off works and not restarting.